# qt.network.ssl: Incompatible version of OpenSSL

Tags: qt, qtcreator, openssl, archlinux

Возникла такая проблема. Поставил QtCreator с помощью онлайн загрузчика. Запускаю проект из шаблонов http example. При попытке выполнить запрос ловлю

> qt.network.ssl: Incompatible version of OpenSSL

Ось Arch Linux x86_64, в системе стоят параллельно openssl-1.0.0 и openssl-1.1

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        13 Sep 11 21:36 libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.1
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root root    498744 Aug 20 08:36 libssl.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    585328 Sep 11 21:36 libssl.so.1.1
```

Слинковать libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.0 я не могу, т.к. почти все приложения в системе зависят от 1.1. Попробовал собрать из исходников 1.0 в динамическую библиотеку и подцепить её к проекту через добавить библиотеку, но тогда по непонятным для меня причинам приложение сначала подгружает системную либу, а уже только затем подгружает мою.[image: Скриншот]

Я так понимаю qt упорно хочет openssl 1.0.0 т.к. тот что у них в репах видимо собран с ней.
Нашёл http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2017-October/028512.html что можно собрать с openssl 1.1 но для меня это пока что нетривиальная задача. Поэтому подскажите какие ещё возможные пути решения этой проблемы существуют?

Comment: Проблемы с последним qt уже нет, т.к. они перешли на 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кто вдруг столкнется, то решение довольно простое и банальное. Qt в репе archlinux собран с 1.1, qt в инсталяторе собран с 1.0, поэтому в qtcreator для текущего kit задаем путь к системному qmake вместо того, что скачивается с сайта. Либо собираем из исходников с 1.1, но в этом немного смысла.

Answer (score 0):

В gentoo достаточно перекомпилировать openssl  с флагом sslv3